# livewire toggle not updating mysql table

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire-3

I have a Laravel Livewire project with Jetstream and can't get my toggle to add/remove a row from a mysql table. It worked under Livewire v2 but no longer does under Livewire v3. How do I resolve this?

My Livewire Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\usersettings;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class UserSettingToggle extends Component
{
 public $settingNumber;
 public $isSwitched;

 public function mount()
 {

 $this->isSwitched = usersettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('setting', $this->settingNumber)->exists();
 }

 public function updating($name, $value)
    {

        if ($name === 'isSwitched') {
            if ($value) {
                    usersettings::create([
                    'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                    'setting' => $this->settingNumber
                    ]);
                }
            else {
                usersettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('setting', $this->settingNumber)->delete();
                }
        }
    }

 public function render()
 {
 return view('livewire.user-setting-toggle');
 }
}
```

My Livewire Blade:

```
<div>
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="userSettingToggle" wire:model="isSwitched">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="userSettingSwitch"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Livewire component is referenced in my Laravel blade file as:

```
<livewire:user-setting-toggle :settingNumber="1" />
```

Comment: In Livewire 3 wire:model is deferred by default, try wire:model.live="isSwitched"